How to correlate all the incidents in BMC remedy through an Spring boot application which are generated during an IT Outage
Connecting BMC Remedy through a Spring boot application
Im on design phase not come up with a solution.
Requirements :
Every Outage is injecting huge set of incidents into the system. My application should connect with Remedy pull/detect all incidents , filter the incidents , correlate it with Outage then resolve once the Outage is over
